# My Selenium Automation script keeps on searching the Element, if its not found on the Page. How do i resolve this issue

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating using Selenium Web driver with Java.
My Script is written to detect a 'Duplicate record created' window message which comes up only when we try to add a 'Duplicate record'.

If the 'Duplicate record window' comes up then my script works absolutely fine.
However, when the 'Duplicate detected window' do not appear, my script waits (Keeps on searching for element) for a long long time before getting Failed. (Approximate time my script waits is 10 to 15 mins).

I want to reduce this time and want my script to 'Fail', if element is not found.

Please note: I have not applied any 'Explicit' or 'Implicit' wait in my code.

```
public boolean Contact_DuplicateDetection() throws InterruptedException { 
    return title_DuplicateRecordsDetected.isDisplayed();    
} 

public void verify_Create_Contact_Duplicate_Detection_TestCase() { 
    Assert.assertTrue(Contact_DuplicateDetection()); 
}
```

Comment: Here is my code:

public boolean Contact_DuplicateDetection() throws InterruptedException
 {
  return title_DuplicateRecordsDetected.isDisplayed(); 
 }
  
 

                                                                                                                              
 public void verify_Create_Contact_Duplicate_Detection_TestCase()
{
Assert.assertTrue(Contact_DuplicateDetection());
}

Answer (score 0):

*Approximate time my script waits is 10 to 15 mins* Its seems you have applied Implicit/Explicit wait in inappropriate manner.

`isDisplay()` function works when your element present in DOM in hidden or visible state. If element not present then obviously error is `NoSuchElementException`.

Here you go with the solution; First change `WebElement title_DuplicateRecordsDetected` to `List<WebElement> title_DuplicateRecordsDetected` in your Page Object
and then make the function as below:

```
public boolean Contact_DuplicateDetection(){

    return title_DuplicateRecordsDetected.isEmpty() ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be if you use explicit wait as sometimes due to heavy load on network the message might appear a bit later. Explicit wait provides timeout functionality too which will help you to reduce the execution time of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Always set an implicit wait. There is no point to wait for more than 1 minute considering user experience and performance.

```
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You can also use try catch to check the element.

```
    public boolean isElementWithXPathExist(String theXpath) {

        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(theXpath))));
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }catch(TimeoutException eT) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hopefully this will help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your active reply all.

I found the solution. Here it is,

```
public boolean verifyContactCreation() throws InterruptedException

{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Assign']")).isEmpty())
    {

        return true;

    }

    else
    {

        return false;

    }


}
```

// Usage of findelements instead of findelement worked for me. Also importantly, applying an Implicit wait of 0 seconds is needed.
Now, my script fails immediately(if element is not found) without waiting for long.